# Group concat up to a maximum number of rows in SQLite

Tags: group-by, sqlite, group-concatenation

I want to group concat several rows, but only up to maximum number of x rows.
Here is the code without the maximum

```sql
create table if not exists csvs (
  id integer,
  csv text
);

insert into csvs (id, csv)
values
  (1, 'one'),
  (1, 'two'),
  (2, 'three'),
  (2, 'four'),
  (2, 'five'),
  (2, 'six');

select id, group_concat(csv)
from csvs
group by id;
```

This yields:

| id | group_concat(csv) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one,two |
| 2 | three,four,five,six |

What I want to achieve is this (so a maximum of 3 entries per row):

| id | group_concat(csv) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one,two |
| 2 | three,four,five |
| 2 | six |

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! How do we know it's not `one, two, three`, `four, five, six` or other permutation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to answer this question, I did the following (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=5e1c1a02dca3c2180bed2bdc47fc5851)):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS csvs 
(
  id  INTEGER,
  csv TEXT
);
```

Populated it (with extra data for testing):

```
INSERT INTO csvs (id, csv) VALUES

(1, '1'), (1, '2'), (1, '3'), (1, '4'), (1, '5'), (1, '6'), (1, '7'), (1, '8'),

(2, '9'), (2, '10'), (2, '11'), (2, '12'), (3, '13'), 
  
(4, '14'), (4, '15'),
  
(5, '16'), (5, '17'), (5, '19'),
  
(6, '20');
```

The key here is to get the `csv`s into groups of 3 - therefore the [modulus operator](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html#mod) (`%`) is the obvious choice, but even with that, there's still a bit of work to be done. I'll go through the steps. Note also that the individual `csv`s are **strings** (TEXT) and do not represent numbers (this saved on typing...). They could be any arbitrary strings.

```
SELECT
  id, csv, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS rn1
FROM
  csvs;
```

Result:

```
id  csv     rn1
 1    1       1   <<-- csv is a string (TEXT), rn is an INTEGER!
 1    2       2
 1    3       3
 1    4       4
 1    5       5
 ...
 ... snipped for brevity
 ...
```

The next step is to start the grouping of the `csv`s by threes.

```
SELECT
  id, csv, rn1, rn1 % 3, (rn1 + 2) % 3 AS cal_1
FROM
(
  SELECT
    id, csv, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS rn1
  FROM
    csvs
)
ORDER BY id;
```

Result:

```
id  csv rn1 rn1 % 3  cal_1
 1    1   1       1      0
 1    2   2       2      1
 1    3   3       0      2
 1    4   4       1      0
 1    5   5       2      1
 1    6   6       0      2
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

So, we can that `rn1 % 3` isn't very helpful - it starts `1`, `2` and then drops back to `0`. The field that interests us is `cal_1`, which starts at `0` and cycles through `1` & `2` and then goes back to `0` - from the beginning!

Now, we have to obtain a handle on our groups of threes - putting each group of three into a separate group.

```
SELECT
  id, csv, rn1, rn1 % 3, (rn1 + 2) % 3 AS cal_1,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, cal_1 ORDER BY id, csv) AS cal_2
FROM
(
  SELECT
    id, csv, rn1, rn1 % 3, (rn1 + 2) % 3 AS cal_1
  FROM
  ( 
    SELECT
      id, csv, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS rn1
    FROM
      csvs
  )
  ORDER BY id
)
ORDER BY id, cal_2, cal_1;
```

Result:

```
id  csv  rn1 rn1 % 3 cal_1 cal_2
 1    1    1       1     0     1
 1    2    2       2     1     1
 1    3    3       0     2     1
 1    4    4       1     0     2
 1    5    5       2     1     2
 1    6    6       0     2     2
 1    7    7       1     0     3
 1    8    8       2     1     3
 2   10    2       2     1     1
 2   11    3       0     2     1
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

So, we now have our `csv` **strings** in groups of 3, by virtue of their `id` field and the `cal_2` field which allows us to do use SQLite's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) built-in aggregate function as follows (I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26929603/470530) helpful):

```
SELECT
  id, GROUP_CONCAT(csv) AS grp
FROM
(
  SELECT
    id, csv, rn1, rn1 % 3, (rn1 + 2) % 3 AS cal_1,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, cal_1 ORDER BY id, rn1) AS cal_2
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      id, csv, rn1, rn1 % 3, (rn1 + 2) % 3 AS cal_1
    FROM
    ( 
      SELECT
        id, csv, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS rn1
      FROM
        csvs
    )
    ORDER BY id
  )
  ORDER BY id, csv
)
GROUP BY id, cal_2
ORDER BY id, rn1;
```

Result:

```
id       grp
1      1,2,3
1      4,5,6
1        7,8
2    10,11,9
2         12
3         13
4      14,15
5   16,17,19
6         20
```

Et voilà!

In order to get the first 3 strings into the first slot per id, we have to keep the rn field down through the SQL - for example, group 2 has 9, 10, 11 & 12. To have the first group of 2 contain 9, 10 & 11, the `rn` is necessary. Unfortunately, there is no way of sorting the strings internally by record - i.e. `9, 10, 11` - it appears as `10, 11, 9` - which is the individual `csv` strings sorted ASCII wise, not numerically.

However, since this example is rather contrived, this shouldn't be an issue for "genuine" strings where the normal ASCII sort order should be acceptable.

Cleaned up (extraneous fields removed) version - same result.

```
SELECT
  id, GROUP_CONCAT(csv) AS grp
FROM
(
  SELECT
    id, csv, rn1,  (rn1 + 2) % 3 AS cal_1,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, cal_1 ORDER BY id, rn1) AS cal_2
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      id, csv, rn1, (rn1 + 2) % 3 AS cal_1
    FROM
    ( 
      SELECT
        id, csv, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS rn1
      FROM
        csvs
    )
    ORDER BY id
  )
  ORDER BY id, csv
)
GROUP BY id, cal_2
ORDER BY id, rn1;
```